# Conditional order by in Propel ORM with a dot in the condition

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, propel

I'm trying to build the following query in propel

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
ORDER BY username = 'foo.bar' DESC, username
```

These options all give me errors:

```
UserQuery::create()
  ->addAscendingOrderByColumn("username = 'foo.bar'")
```

This is caused due to the ".". Without it's working

Errormessage:

```
"Criteria:(Error: Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined table: username = 'foo)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is not possible in Propel 1 (nor do I know if it's possible with Propel 2). I had a similar issue:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/propel-users/sz3wA_bdF8k

And upon further investigation, I discovered that you can only pass column names and fully qualified names (table.column) into the `ORDER BY` methods. Switch statements do work in `->withColumn` clauses though, for anyone who's trying to do something similar.